# Create_at Admin time is not correctly showing in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, time

my function is 
it is showing like Feb 22,2017 12:00:00 AM 
i need to display current time.

```
 public function ws_getPunchHistory($custid,$intime,$outtime,$inlocation,$outlocation,$punchstatus,$create_at)
     {




   if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    }
    else{
        $res["error"] = "Invalid request";
        return $res;
    }
    $res = array();
    $data = array();
    $custid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
    if ($custid != '')
    {   
        $date= date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        //$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
         $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->getCollection()
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('manager_id','64648')
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('create_at', array('eq' =>$current))
                                                           ->addFieldToFilter('punch_in_time', array('null' => true))
                                                           ->getFirstItem();

    //print_r($collection);


        try{
            $data = array(
                'manager_id' => strval($custid),
                'punch_in_time' => strval($intime),
                'punch_out_time' => strval($outtime),
                'in_coordinates' => strval($inlocation),
                'out_coordinates' => strval($outlocation),
                'status' => $punchstatus,
                'create_at' => $create_at
                );
            // print_r($data);
            $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_asmtracker';
           $smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setData($data)->save();

            $res['code'] = 200;
            $res['asmtracker'] = 'ok';               
        }catch(exception $exception){
            $res['code'] = 400;
            $res['asmtrakcer'] = $exception->getMessage();
        }

    }else{
        $res['code'] = 500;
        //$res['asmtrakcer'] = $exception->getMessage();
    }
    return $res;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
$date= date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

with this :

```
$current = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: still not coming !! :(

Answer (score 0):

Then it will be return

```
$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$res['current'] = $current;
```

If you want formating the date

```
$current = date('M d,Y H:i:s A');
```

Output **Feb 22,2017 12:27:06 PM**